# How do I load url from Bundle in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, bundle

I cannot load page using link that is passed from a previous Activity.

The code is as follows

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_webpage);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    /*Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = b.getString(DeviceDetails.URL_KEY);*/

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(DeviceDetails.URL_KEY);
    //String url = "http://google.pl/nexus/4";
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, when I use String url="http://google.pl/nexus/4" all seems to be fine. And I'm totally sure that my activity gets the url from `getIntent` because I debugged it.

**UPD1:**

```
String inputUrl = detUrlEditText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(DeviceDetails.this, ShowWebPageActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(URL_KEY, inputUrl);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Previous Activity. It is guaranteed to pass url because I debugged it. And toast also shows passed url in `ShowWebPageActivity`.

Comment: can you show the other activity where you send the link

Comment: It's worth noting also that you are using an `Extra` on an `Intent` which is a different concept than `Bundle`

Comment: if u comment the next line webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); does it work maybe the problem is not the intent

Comment: can you be a bit more specific then "I cannot load page" What do you see on the screen when it tries to load? Does it force close? Is there anything put into the Logcat when it tries to load? Last ditch guess: Do you have the `Internet` permission in your manifest? I think if you forget that then WebView will silent fail.

Comment: Have internet permission. WebView just shows white page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `view.loadUrl(url)` inside the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

I've seen examples elsewhere that do this and I don't understand why, this shouldn't be necessary.

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` should return true when you are handing the URL and the WebView should not load it, and return false when the WebView should proceed with loading the URL.

You *could* call `view.loadUrl()` if you decide that the WebView should open a *different* page than the URL parameter, for example.

Here's an example of a `WebViewClient` subclass:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (handleWithSystemBrowser(url)) {
           Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
           if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
               startActivity(intent);
           }
           return true;   // tells WebView that we specifically handled the URL, so don't load it
        }

        return false;   // go ahead and load it in the WebView
    }

    private boolean handleWithSystemBrowser(String url) {

        // put your code here to check the URL
        // return true if you want the device browser to display the URL
        // return false if you want the WebView to load the URL
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it opens my url (String url = "http://google.pl/nexus/4";) in browser. When getting url from previous activity - still blank page.